# Azure Export from localDb fails to make index

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have a very simple table in a (localDb)\V11.0.  I've used the Management Studio Wizard to create a Clustered index.
When I run the Import Export Wizard against the localDb to export this table I get an error:

"**Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again**."

The Wizard creates the table in the Azure Db without the index and then complains about not having an index.

Again, the source Db has a clustered index.

This has worked in the past (Exporting from localDb to AzureSQL).  I'm stumped as this is a VERY simple table.

I've tried the default as well as the ".Net Framework Data Provider for SqlServer" as mentioned in another SO question.
I'm using SQL Server 2012 Management Studio.

Comment: why don't you give a try to [SQL Azure Migration Wizzard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). It is far more advanced than the `Generate Scripts` task in the SSMS. And the SQL Azure MW automatically creates clustered indexes (based on primary key) even if the table does not have such!

Comment: Well that wasn't fun.  The SQL AZure Migration Wizzard  will NOT connect to my (localDb): may have to do with the fact that I have SQL Server 2012 and not 2010 as is listed as a requirement.  Then again maybe the tool just doesn't work.  As installing an old version of SQL on top of a new version is probably a very bad idea (this very true for Visual Studio)..  I'm stuck uninstalling and then reinstalling all for the hope that this unsupported tool can move tables... This is looking like Azure SQL was not a good choice at this point.

Comment: I got it working. For SQL 2012 you must use the ver 4.09 of the Azure Migration Wizzard.  Other than a little issue with the connection string (it doesn't like "tcp:...." as a server name.  It brought over the table schema and data... astaykov THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are seeing this error, but I always suggest to use the [SQL Azure Migration Wizzard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/). It is far more advanced than the `Generate Scripts` task in the SSMS.

Plus the SQL Azure MW automatically creates clustered indexes (based on primary key) even if the table does not have such! Another plus of the SQL Azure MW is that, it is developed by a person who is in the SQL Azure team.